# Gnuplot, how can I get hh:mm on x axis

Tags: gnuplot

With this datafile (x.txt)

```
20180522110000 6.03
20180522144500 10.44
20180523071501 5.17
```

and this command file (x.gnuplot)

```
set term png
set output "x.png"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
set format x "%H:%M"
plot "x.txt" using :2 w lines
```

and using gnuplot 5.0
I don't get the desired x-labels. I get only

```
00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00
```

not (something more like, give or take some details...)

```
11:00   ....  07:15
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
I was missing "1"

**Wrong:**

```
plot "x.txt" using :2 w lines
```

**Correct:**

```
plot "x.txt" using 1:2 w lines
```